# Json request body to java object with spring-boot

Tags: java, spring

I have the following JSON Request

```
{
  "FreightCalculationRequest": {
    "Products": [
      {
        "sku": "123",
        "size": "S",
        "quantity": "1",
        "shipAlone": "True",
        "itemType": "Shoe"
      },
      {
        "sku": "123",
        "size": "S",
        "quantity": "1",
        "shipAlone": "True",
        "itemType": "Shoe"
      }
    ],
    "ShipToZip": "54452",
    "IsCommercial": "True"
  }
}
```

I am trying to send this request to the API controller method as a custom java object, and then return that same object as a json formatted string. I am getting a response through postman however, for products, and shiptoZip i get a null, and for isCommercial I get false, but i don't even have false as a value for isCommercial in the request. What's going on? I don't know how to debug very well in Java as i basically am checking my app every time by typing mvn spring-boot:start

here is my object that I am returning and using as a parameter into the controller method.

```
public class FreightCalculationRequest {

    private Product[] Products;
    private String ShipToZip;
    private boolean IsCommercial;

    public Product[] getProducts() { return this.Products; }
    public void setProducts(Product[] itemsRequest) { this.Products = itemsRequest; }

    public String getShipToZip() { return this.ShipToZip; }
    public void setShipToZip(String ShipToZip) { this.ShipToZip = ShipToZip; }

    public boolean getIsCommercial() { return this.IsCommercial; }
    public void setIsCommercial(boolean IsCommercial) { this.IsCommercial = IsCommercial; }

}
```

and here is the controller method im calling

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,  method = RequestMethod.POST)
FreightCalculationRequest TestCall(@RequestBody FreightCalculationRequest calculationRequest) {
    return calculationRequest;

}
```

Why is my response not showing the same as the request coming in.

update:
I added @JsonProperty to my variables, and now the response looks like such

```
{
    "isCommercial": false,
    "shipToZip": null,
    "products": null,
    "Products": null,
    "ShipToZip": null,
    "IsCommercial": false
}
```

Kind of lost a bit, also realized I can save my changes while mvn is running and it will auto compile the changes

Update:
So the itemType in my json was actually throwing an error when I initally remove the wrapping of "FreightCalculationRequest" in the json response, so i thought that was the issue, however itemType is actually an object in the code so it was due to me not putting in a valid property and reading the json parsing error thoroughly,  There were two solutions for me, wrapping the response in another class, or remove the FreightCalculationWrapping.

I also learned that I need to add @JsonProperty to map the json

Thanks SO

Comment: Your JSON request looks like another model class wraps the `FreightCalculationRequest` properties. Unwrap it, and it should work.

Comment: @TheHeadRush I tried this, and now instead of getting a response, i get an json parsing error.

Comment: This is a case of not following naming conventions. If you follow proper conventions, this will work fine. e.g. `shipToZip` not `ShipToZip`. It's odd anyway, since you're mixing naming conventions in your payloads.

Comment: I see the error I was getting was actually a different issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am getting a response through postman however, for products, and
>   shiptoZip i get a null, and for isCommercial I get false, but i don't
>   even have false as a value for isCommercial in the request. What's
>   going on?

You'll have to wrap the **FreightCalculationRequest** in a new model class.

Make a new **Wrapper** class,

```
public class FreightCalculationRequestWrapper {
    @JsonProperty("FreightCalculationRequest")
    private FreightCalculationRequest freightCalculationRequest;

    ...
}
```

Use this new **Wrapper** class to handle your requests:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,  method = RequestMethod.POST)
FreightCalculationResponse TestCall(@RequestBody FreightCalculationRequestWrapper calculationRequest) {
    return calculationRequest;

}
```

Also, the property names in your JSON start with a capital letter.

If you are using Jackson then you can use `@JsonProperty(...)` annotation on your model fields to map them properly.

**For Example:**

```
public class FreightCalculationRequest {
    @JsonProperty("Products")
    private Product[] Products;

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Do I need to do this for the objects within the Request object

Comment: @boo You need to erap it because your JSON has `FreightCalculationRequest` at the root and not `Products`.

Comment: Okay I got it started and I added the annotation to Products and I now get a response of `{
    "isCommercial": false,
    "shipToZip": null,
    "products": null,
    "Products": null
}` and when I add the annotations to all the variables, it leaves the lowercase names in the json response.

Comment: So I'm getting everything working except one last issue, now the products is showing whats in the json as a response, but it also duplicates it as a "Products" object to and so I have two products arrays in my response, trying to tweak it around, but I have my mapping set.

Comment: @boo Have a look at `@JsonSetter` and `@JsonGetter` annotations. You'll want them on your Getter-Setters.